# Handling post request with form data with multiple identical names in jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, form-data

On the website a ajax post request is send to a jsp file, that reads the body and sends back a response that is used to refresh a part of the page. In the Ajax request I can see that the data with identical names is send. However, I can not read the data. With unique names I can retrieve the data in jsp. Changing the way the data is send is not an option, because there is too much code build around it.

[image: Form Data Ajax Post Request]

This code reads the form data and prints it back on the website.

```
<h1>Facet <c:out value="${pageContext.request.getParameter('facet')}" /></h1>
<h1>Minprice <c:out value="${pageContext.request.getParameter('minPrice')}" /></h1>
```

"Minprice" is printed to the screen, but "Facet" isn't.

[image]

Comment: It might be an array, try `${pageContext.request.getParameter('facet')[0]}`

Comment: Thanks for your response Musa. It is not an array, but a string. 
"<h1>Facet <c:out value="${pageContext.request.getParameter('facet').class}" /></h1>" gives me "Facet class java.lang.String"

Answer (score 1):

I found it! The request class has a different method for handling multiple identical parameter names, like which is often the case with the `<select>` and `<option>` tags. It is the "getParameterValues()" method. The following code gives me the result I was looking for.

```
<c:forEach items="${pageContext.request.getParameterValues('facet')}" var="item">
    <h1>Facet ${item}</h1>
</c:forEach>
```